# Google Fonts API

Tags: google-font-api

Am using https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=_key for getting google fonts lists and details of the fonts..

But am getting the following error.

```
{"error"=>{"errors"=>
    [{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"dailyLimitExceededUnreg", 
    "message"=>"Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
    , "extendedHelp"=>"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}], 
    "code"=>403, "message"=>"Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"}}.
```

I got stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that Google has stated that you've exceeded the daily limit for accessing the service.

Basically to protect themselves from denial of service attacks (and in some cases to generate revenue from their projects) they limit the number of accesses you can make to service.

You should follow the link and sign up for an account with them so that you can possibly avoid the limit.

Comment: But am trying for first time.. how come the daily limit exceeds? Actually i have created an api account today morning only.. so no way to exceed the limit.. Is there some other font API suggestion from your side?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using that exact URL, then that's the problem. You need to replace the final `_key` in the URL with the key they supplied.